# Rendering Box2D Chain Shape in libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I'm using the chain shape as the walls for a 2D race track. Everything works perfectly with the Debug Renderer, and I'm able to render other objects simply with sprites.

**But how do I render the chain shape (without using the debug renderer)?** I see nothing about this in the documentation.

I'm using R.U.B.E. to create the track, so the chain shapes are not really a part of the libgdx code. This is what the full map looks like in RUBE:
[It's just 2 chain shapes with many vertices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIkP8.png)

I use libgdx to load the Json file created by RUBE (which loads the chain shapes), then I spawn the player within the 2 chain shapes.

Any advice is welcome.

EDIT: The best solution I can think of is to collect the vertices of the chain shape, and use those to draw a line with no relation to the actual chain shape. However, this seems more like a workaround, and I feel like there's an easier/more direct way to display chain shapes.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody else running into the same issue: it seems to be the case that there isn't really a way to render chain shapes. The solution to my problem is to render an image of the track, then create the chain shapes on the boundaries.